# Angular reloading page when changing route param

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript, routes

so im doing a web app
this web app has a lot of pages and inside one of them has tabs.
to do routes kind of, I used the ng-view directive for the parent page and and in a litle div that has a ng-switch, and displays diferent tabs depending of the route param (matched with a var in $scope), and showing the content in ng-includes inside them, the problem im having is that every time I change tab, the page reloads. the view its the same but the tab its different, the tabs are working but i have a google map in this page so its a mayor performance issue that the web gets reloaded every time i change tab.

here its a basic example of what im doing (im using coffeescript, and jade)

index.jade

```
body(ng-view)
```

page.jade

```
section.menu.pull-left
 nav
  ul
    li(ng-class="{active: route.tab == 'order'}")
      a(href="#page/order" target="_self") 
        i.fa.fa-cab
        small order
    li(ng-class="{active: route.tab == 'favorites'}")
      a(href="#page/favorites" target="_self") 
        i.fa.fa-star
        small favorites
```

and the tabs

```
.display(ng-switch="route.tab")
  .tab(ng-switch-when="order")
    div(ng-include="'views/page/order.html'")
  .tab(ng-switch-when="favorites") 
    div(ng-include="'views/page/favorites.html'")
```

the route file

```
app.config ['$routeProvider', ($routeProvider) ->
$routeProvider
 .when '/',
   templateUrl : 'views/login.html'
   controller  : 'loginCtrl'
   tab         : ''

 .when '/page/:tab',
   templateUrl : 'views/page.html'
   controller  : 'pageCtrl'  

 ]
```

page.jade must be static and te tabs have to change. i dont know why its doing this, the controller is empty basicly. i dont know what to do! please help

Comment: You really haven't explained what the exact problem is. Sure it has to do with page reload but what triggers the reload and on what path. Also looks like your href's are needing a `/` after `#`

Comment: @charlietfl " the problem im having is that every time I change tab, the page reloads."

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your `href's` are incorrectly formatted

try changing:

```
href="#page/order"
```

To

```
href="#/page/order"
```

Might also remove the target from `<a>` tags

Comment: im geting the same result, I use only the '#'  because its how angular documentation shows routing proccess. :(

Comment: did you remove `target`?

Comment: yes, no results, I dont understand why changing route param variable its causing the page to reload.

Comment: i also try adding this `reloadOnSearch: false` to the route configuration and didnt do anithing

Comment: create a demo that replicates problem

Comment: after investigating a little bit, i didnt see anyone try this so i guess its a nogo, i changed the route param with a scope variable and its doing the job, it doesent seem clean to me, but it does the job.
so, for what i know, changing a route param in angular, reloads the page, its kind of lame if you think that is a single application oriented framework.
sorry, making a fidle of this would take me much more time, than fix it this way.

Comment: angular router (prior to 1.4) is OK,  suggest looking at angular-ui-router for a lot more powerful one. The angular one just went through major overhaul/upgrade...but i haven't dug into it's new capabilities yet

Comment: issue seems strange regardless of router though. Is this an old version of angular? Is router same version?

Comment: angular version and route are 1.4.1

Comment: OK... there may be things in new router I'm not familiar with. It is a lot more advanced in 1.4 than prior versions. May even require different config. Have you checked docs?

Comment: yeah i thougth it was odd  as well, but i its not like it doesent make sense, if you do use route params as subsections or sub-products or lower lavel pages, reloading the page its not a problem at all, but im tring to update only one part of one view (using partials) in fact it works well, but i have a google map in this view so i can not afford to reload every time i change the tab/route. I dont know if angular does this on porpouse because its incorrect or may be then not forseen this kind of use of route params

Comment: looks like new router using different configuration from quick searching I just did

Comment: as i see, they use route params like `:param` exactly the way i have been using it, i read the documentation and it hasent changed a lot, im kind of new in angular so i do not know how older versions worked.
anyway,  using a scope variable to change tabs seems odd to me, but in my search in the web i saw bizare things people do, like scope watchs an such... so may be this is not so bad